# cannot insert null in one to many relationship hibernate annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations

I have a class A{Set b .....} which holds references of class B as Set. It is one to many relationship.
Both class have sequencer in oracle. I put cascade to all in hibernate annotations. When i save class A, it gives me error that cannot insert null B.a_id . A-id is not nullable in my database. How can i persist this relationship.

Comment: Show us some more code, please.. This is too little information to answer your question.

Comment: I annotated class b in A as @OneToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
    private Set<B> b;                                                                      Annotated class B as usual. This is a unidirectional relationship from A->B. a_id column in table B is not nullable. When hibernate tries to save class B, it not able to find value for a_id. When i remove this mapping, then class A is successfully saved with auto generated value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> This is a unidirectional relationship from A->B. a_id column in table B is not nullable. When hibernate tries to save class B, it not able to find value for a_id.

Well, did you try to make the `JoinColumn` non `nullable`?

```
@OneToMany 
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL}) 
@JoinColumn(name="A_ID", nullable=false)
private Set<B> b;
```

#### See also

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [6.2.1. Collection foreign keys](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-foreignkeys)

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is working now. It is foolish to not see all attributes.

Comment: Now it is successfully working. I can one insert statement into A and one for B ,then update statement for table B. Since insert statement doesn't throw exception i wonder if hibernate insert temporary values into a_Id.

Comment: If i change the mapping from OnetoMany to OnetoOne, then it again give cannot insert null sql exception. How can i then persist OnetoOne mapping.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by using the mappedBy attribute of the @OneToMany annotation in Class A:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "m_a")
private Set<B> b;
```

Here, m_a is the field in Class B that refers to Class A:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "aId", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne
private A m_a;
```

This way, the @JoinColumn is only specified in one place, no duplicated code.

Comment: That's because you have bi-directional relationship. It's a bit different from author unidirectional relationship.